# How to Convert Oracle 10g reports programmatically into Excel?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

i want to know how can i convert my oracle 10g reports into excel or get direct output in excel of mine report using PLSQL(programmatically) , currently i convert my report into XML format and then open it in excel manually, but this method is not helpful for Matrix reports, simple reports converts perfectly but Matrix are not !

Please guide me how can i achieve this task!

Warmest Regards !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PL/SQL package at https://github.com/commi235/xlsx_builder -- you provide the SQL query, it writes out an XLSX format file.  It works quite well as supports a lot of features such  as formatting, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Stewart  for your reply, This PL/SQL package is work on query to sheet method basically, but it can not fulfill my requirement because an oracle report query has number of summary and formula columns in its data model, and we can not use these columns in query to sheet method because these are implement by Report Builder Tool.